# How to count the number of binds in a AngularJS application

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

How can I count the number of data binds in my AngularJS application?

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("ng-binding").length`

Answer (score 0):

```
function getScopes(root) {
    var scopes = [];
    function traverse(scope) {
        scopes.push(scope);
        if (scope.$$nextSibling)
            traverse(scope.$$nextSibling);
        if (scope.$$childHead)
            traverse(scope.$$childHead);
    }
    traverse(root);
    return scopes;
}
var rootScope = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll("[ng-app]")).scope();
var scopes = getScopes(rootScope);
var watcherLists = scopes.map(function(s) { return s.$$watchers; });
_.uniq(_.flatten(watcherLists)).length;
```

Reference: http://larseidnes.com/2014/11/05/angularjs-the-bad-parts/